# Cross product of locally conformally flat manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The cross product of two locally conformally flat manifolds may not be a locally conformally flat one. Does anyone have a very simple example to show this?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{S}^2$ is a very simple example in my opinion.

Comment: @mfl Whereas $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{S}^2$ is again locally conformally flat?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{S}^2$ is locally conformally flat.

Comment: How to see $\mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{S}^2$ is not locally conformally flat? Thank @mfl

Comment: Check that the Weyl tensor doesn't vanish.